# Dúvida ao usar ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, query

Estou tentando usar `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` na minha *query* e por algum motivo não está funcionando.

Eu retiro o `ID` e não uso `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`: os valores são salvos em uma nova linha no banco.

Exemplo:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO estoque ( cod_produto, dsc_produto, preco_produto, qtd_estoque, qtd_limitador) VALUES ('".$cod_produto."', '".$dsc_produto."', '".$preco_produto."', '".$qtd_estoque."', '".$qtd_limitador."');
```

Código com defeito:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

            $id = $_GET[id];
            $cod_produto = $_POST['cod_produto'];
            $dsc_produto = $_POST['dsc_produto'];
            $preco_produto = $_POST['preco_produto'];
            $qtd_estoque = $_POST['qtd_estoque'];
            $qtd_limitador = $_POST['qtd_limitador'];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO estoque (id, cod_produto, dsc_produto, preco_produto, qtd_estoque, qtd_limitador) VALUES ('".$id."','".$cod_produto."', '".$dsc_produto."', '".$preco_produto."', '".$qtd_estoque."', '".$qtd_limitador."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (cod_produto=$cod_produto, dsc_produto=$dsc_produto)";

            $mysql = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
                if (!mysql) {
                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error()); 
                }

                else {
                    echo "Feito";

                }

echo $id;
}
```

Não apresenta nenhum erro, apenas não salva nenhum valor no banco.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse artigo, ele exemplifica o uso o ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
Eu tive o mesmo problema resolvi com esse artigo. Boa sorte http://blog.glaucocustodio.com/2012/10/26/atualizar-registro-se-existir-senao-inserir-no-mysql-com-on-duplicate-key-update/ Consulte a documentação também se necessário https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 3):

Eu já tinha olhada o link e não me ajudou muito, mas acabei descobrindo que o erro era sobre como eu chamava as strings.

Após o ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE eu chamo as strings de forma simples, quando deveria usar '".$string."', por isso não estava funcionando.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO estoque (id, cod_produto, dsc_produto, preco_produto, qtd_estoque, qtd_limitador) VALUES ('".$id."','".$cod_produto."', '".$dsc_produto."', '".$preco_produto."', '".$qtd_estoque."', '".$qtd_limitador."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (cod_produto=$cod_produto, dsc_produto=$dsc_produto)"
```

Também, com um pouco mais de pesquisa vi que é usar um UPDATE ao invés de ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tem mais perfomance nesse caso. A segunda opção teria grande utilidade numa importação onde deve-se evitar duplicações.

Dessa forma, segue o código correto:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

            $id = $_GET[id];
            $cod_produto = $_POST['cod_produto'];
            $dsc_produto = $_POST['dsc_produto'];
            $preco_produto = $_POST['preco_produto'];
            $qtd_estoque = $_POST['qtd_estoque'];



            $sql = "UPDATE estoque SET cod_produto='".$cod_produto."', dsc_produto='".$dsc_produto."', preco_produto='".$preco_produto."', qtd_estoque='".$qtd_estoque."' WHERE id='".$id."'";

            $mysql = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
                if (!mysql) {
                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error()); 
                }

                else {
                    echo "Feito";

                }

echo $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $id = $_GET[id];
    $cod_produto = $_POST['cod_produto'];
    $dsc_produto = $_POST['dsc_produto'];
    $preco_produto = $_POST['preco_produto'];
    $qtd_estoque = $_POST['qtd_estoque'];

    $sql = <<<SQL
        UPDATE estoque 
        SET cod_produto = ?, 
            dsc_produto = ?, 
            preco_produto = ?, 
            qtd_estoque = ? 
        WHERE id = ?;
SQL;
    $stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);

    if (!$stmt) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }

    // http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters
    $stmt->bind_param('isdii', $cod_produto, $dsc_produto, $preco_produto, $qtd_estoque)
    $stmt->execute();

    printf("%d linhas alteradas.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

    $stmt->close();
}
```

É apenas um complemento para que teu site não sofra SQLInjection, usa [prepared statements](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) para a conexão.

Os caracteres dos parâmetros são os seguintes:

- **`i`**: type integer
- **`d`**: type double
- **`s`**: type string
- **`b`**: variable is a blob and will be sent in packets

Answer (score 0):

Acho que falta as aspas simples nas variaves do on duplicate key update.

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (cod_produto='$cod_produto', dsc_produto='$dsc_produto')"
```